# Did the Joker say that the villains probably work for Google?

Tags: dialogue, the-lego-batman-movie

English is not my native language, therefore the question. Did The Joker in *The Lego Batman Movie* say to the pilot that some of the villains probably work for Google?

> **Pilot:** Ok, are you making some of those up?
>
> **The Joker:** Nope, they are
>   all real... probably work for Google.

[This](https://youtu.be/i6WM-pih8xA) is the clip with the video.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm having difficulty finding a copy of the movie's script online to confirm (lots of "early drafts" from like 2013, but no final shooting scripts that I can find - in particular none containing this scene) **HOWEVER** I'm fairly certain that what the Joker actually said was this:

> Nope, they're all real... Probably worth a Google.

He's using "Google" as a verb - suggesting the pilot should go online and "google" (ie: search for) the more obscure super-villains he named.

Comment: I thought at least the Condiment King was made up, but nope; he's a real villain.

Comment: Could he be saying that they are worth a [googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) monetarily (i.e. $10^100)?

Comment: http://comicsalliance.com/ask-chris-329-lego-batman-obscure-villains/

Comment: @Thunderforge Doesn't make much sense in the context of the question he was asked by the pilot... but then again, we are talking about The Joker...

Comment: @Steve-O I've never seen the movie and the video clip is just of these lines, so I don't know what the context of the conversation is.

Comment: @Thunderforge, the context is that Joker has teamed up with all villains. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: Seen it recently, and yes. I don't recall his exact phrasing, but that is what he meant. He lists tons of stupid named villains and in the end says something in the lines: (Don't believe me? Probably worth a google.)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Screenrant](http://screenrant.com/lego-batman-movie-video-joker-dc-villains/), as well as a couple of other reviews I looked at, The Joker is indeed saying "worth a google". In the English language, the proper name Google has become slang for looking something up on the Internet - even when not using the [popular search engine](http://www.google.com). The term is typically used as a verb (i.e. - "google it"), but can also be used as a noun (i.e. - "let's do a quick google and find out"). It is the latter which The Joker is using in this context.

> For anyone who has seen a Batman film, read a Batman comic, played a
>   Batman game, or has a general knowledge about the character, some of
>   these villains will be recognizable. Riddler (Conan O’Brien),
>   Scarecrow (Jason Mantzoukas), Bane (Doug Benson), Two-Face (Billy Dee
>   Williams), Catwoman (Zoe Kravitz), and Penguin should be familiar, but
>   after that, it takes a really hardcore Batman fan to recognize the
>   other villains.
>
> Crazy Quilt, Eraser, Polka Dot Man, Mime, Tarantula, King Tut, Orca,
>   Killer Moth, March Harriet, Zodiac Master, Killer Ghost, Clock King,
>   Calendar Man, Kite Man, Catman, Zebra Man, and Condiment King, on the
>   other hand, will be new to most. Just like the pilot in the video,
>   most may wonder if these are all really villains Batman has faced over
>   the years. **As Galifianakis' Joker says, "It’s worth a Google."**

SOURCE: http://screenrant.com/lego-batman-movie-video-joker-dc-villains/